# Meteor Account Credential Assignment

Tags: javascript, facebook, meteor, comments

I have a Meteor app that works with a Facebook app for user login. On the actual hosted version, the login makes use of the actual Facebook app but in localhost in development, the app uses a Facebook test app.
The problem is that when I switch over from development to deploying, I need to comment out the credentials for production and uncomment the credentials for development. How could I solve this issue?

```
  // Removes the config b/c dupliation error and re-defines it
  // Facebook API config

 // Since Facebook Test app has been created, wrap this in conditional that only executes if on Amazon server and not localhost


 // STRICTLY - Production
 // ServiceConfiguration.configurations.remove({
 //   service: "facebook"
 // });

 // ServiceConfiguration.configurations.insert({
 //   service: 'facebook',
 //   appId: Meteor.settings.FacebookId,
 //   secret: Meteor.settings.FacebookSecret
 // });


 // STRICTLY - Dev
   ServiceConfiguration.configurations.remove({
    service: "facebook"
 });

  ServiceConfiguration.configurations.insert({
    service: 'facebook',
    appId: 'id',
    secret: 'secret'
  });
```

Comment: have the code remove and add new service by meteor settings and you just change the `settings.json` file? usually it's separated folders for dev/production so it solve this problem also.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should add **dev** and **prod** variables to your `settings.json` file, and load them locally with `meteor --settings settings.json`.  The settings.json file would look something like this:

```
{ 
"dev": {
  "public": {
    "facebook": {
      "appId": "abc123"
     }
   },
  "private": {
    "facebook": {
      "secret": "456def789"
     }
   }
 },
"prod": {
  "public": {
    "facebook": {
      "appId": "def234"
     }
   },
  "private": {
    "facebook": {
      "secret": "789ghi101112"
     }
   }
}
```

You could then access them just as you were before: `Meteor.settings.dev.public.facebook.appId`.

The public/private may be overkill for your project (and I may have messed up the brackets), but this should convey the general concept.  For more info, check out this oft-cited [post](http://joshowens.me/environment-settings-and-security-with-meteor-js/).

Comment: I noticed that in some of your answers you use code snippets inappropriately. Code snippets should be used for what is supported client-side on SO, like jQuery or plain JavaScript, not for JSON data or Meteor code.

Comment: I know how to access my credentials. My trouble is with dynamically switching the credentials based on whether I'm in localhost or not. On the deployed server for this app, the code I posted works great. When I run meteor run --settings settings.json however, the Facebook credentials for login is set to for the **Public** Facebook app and not for the **Test** App.  You suggested I make variables for the test app credentials. I could do this but this wouldn't solve the conundrum I'm having.